# JFLEX regular expressions for string starts with

Tags: java, regex, flex-lexer, jflex

I'm new with this jflex and regular expressions I read a lot even though I know I faced the solution in the manual but really I can't understand these regular expressions. I want simple read a text file with jflex and return every line that starts with `name =`  or `name=` but this was a pain for me for 1 week I'm reading all regular expressions in the jflex document but I can't understand which one I can use to achieve it anyone can help me out? with jflex rules and any code to contain that?

this is the example input and output

```
bla bla bla
bla bla bla
name=StackOverFlow
name = ThisIsGo
bla bla bla
```

Output:

StackOverFLow

ThisIsGo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to match something placed after the equal sign preceded by the word `name`, then you could simply describe that syntax and use a capturing group to enclose the value after the equal sign.

```
name\s*=\s*(.+)
```

##### Test Link

Here you can test the regex above:

https://regex101.com/r/FMXSDK/1

##### Code Snippet

Your code would look like this:

```
String str = "bla bla bla\n" +
        "bla bla bla\n" +
        "name=StackOverFlow\n" +
        "name = ThisIsGo\n" +
        "bla bla bla";

Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("name\\s*=\\s*(.+)");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(str);

while (matcher.find()){
    System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
}
```

##### Output

```
StackOverFlow
ThisIsGo
```

Comment: @Mobinkh So did you translate Dan's regex to JFlex? Or did you throw JFlex away and just use Dan's Java code?

Comment: @sepp2k i only used his regex in my code